# jQuery .on("keyup") only fires once after ajax call, does not update if value is changed, using it up update city & state with zipcode

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is my jquery with ajax call

```
$(".zipfield").on("keyup", function(){
            var city = $(this).closest(".addressBlock").find(".cityfield");
            var state = $(this).closest(".addressBlock").find(".statefield");

            if ($(this).val() !== "" && (city.val() === "" || city.val() == null) && (state.val() === "" || state.val() == null) ) {
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "<?= $this->baseUrl();?>/search/zip",
                    data: {zip: $(this).val()},
                    complete: function (r, e) {
                        var data = JSON.parse(r.responseText);
                        if (data.status === "OK") {
                            city.val(data.city);
                            state.val(data.state);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

any suggestions as to how I can get it updated everytime I input a new value for the zipfield

Comment: Is there anything on the page that replaces the `$(".zipfield")` element with another element that does not have the event listener attached? Remember: event listeners are attached via the `on()` event, which you might have executing one time (ie, right after the page loads).

Comment: What happens if you replace the `$.ajax(...)` call with a `console.log('now search for zip')`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like in the lines

```
var city = $(this).closest(".addressBlock").find(".cityfield");
var state = $(this).closest(".addressBlock").find(".statefield");
```

using `$(this).closest(".className")` is not actually getting the elements and hence, not setting them after your ajax call.

I don't believe you can use class names in `closest` in jquery. You should probably find the closest `tr` or maybe even `form` instead. From there you can use the `find` with the class names `cityfield` and `statefield`.

Comment: its actually gets the information and sets it in the city and state field but when I change the zip code it does not update any information, it does not call the ajax call a second time

Comment: Have you tried changing `$(".zipfield").on("keyup", function(){` to `$(".zipfield").keyup(function() {`?

Comment: yup, tried that and ```on.(change) ``` and ```.change()```
It seems like it will update after inputting the zip code once to twice but never a third time. I even tried wrapping it in an IF statement to see if that would help. It's frustrating.

Comment: Have you checked the network tab to check that the requests are being made and received as expected?

Comment: yes, it is calling the correct controller and action and getting the appropriate request